# Yahoo Finance Screener - Web scraping with R

Tags: r, web-scraping, yahoo-finance

I am trying to get the 1919 matching stocks from this Yahoo Finance screener:

https://finance.yahoo.com/screener/unsaved/3fc05c68-7294-4165-bff5-f8859a2533e5?count=25&offset=0
using R.

I normally use XPath but I can't get it with SelectorGadget at this website.

Could somebody help me to get these data. Maybe be using html_nodes and html_attr?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not public data (at least for me), so you may not get many replies. You could try pasting a sample of the raw data here.

Comment: I hope the URL is reachable now

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
library(curl)
library(XML)
readHTMLtable(
  readLines(
    curl('https://finance.yahoo.com/screener/unsaved/3fc05c68-7294-4165-bff5-f8859a2533e5?count=25&offset=0')
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you. I would appreciate you to show me the full code to get it as I am a beginner in R.